# Firebase Realtime Rules: Allowing multiple Users Access to Data

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

So I have my Database structured like this, the owner gets set when the group is created and the owner the should have the permission to add other Users to allowed so they can access and edit the data too.

```
-Groups
   |-Groupname
      |- Owner: string
      |- Allowed: List<string>
      |- Data: all the data
```

So my attempt were these rules but they dont work when I use the playground feature with a saved uid under owner or allowed:

```
"Groups" : {
      "$group": {
        ".read": "auth != null && (data.child('Owner').val() === auth.uid || data.child('Allowed').val() === auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth != null && (data.child('Owner').val() === auth.uid || data.child('Allowed').val() === auth.uid)"
                }
           }
```

And would a User still be able to create a new group when these rules would work?
Pictures of the Database and Errors: [image: 1]  [image: 2]  [image: 3]

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a screenshot of the playground, showing what you tried, the error you get, and the data that is relevant to the rules?

Comment: Did it! If you need more or clarification just ask me!

Comment: You're not supposed to have `"`s around the UID value in the playground.

Comment: Sorry that was my sloppy copying it still returns the same error without them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in the Realtime Database, [avoid using arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and use a map instead.

Change this:

```json
"Allowed": {
  "0": "8ZiQGBPFkiZOLgLJBgDeLw9ie9D3",
  "1": "KEuhrxnAWXS0dnotjhjFAYUOcm42",
  "2": "48yULftKSxgyS84ZJC4hs4ug4Ei2"
}
```

to this:

```json
"Allowed": {
  "8ZiQGBPFkiZOLgLJBgDeLw9ie9D3": true,
  "KEuhrxnAWXS0dnotjhjFAYUOcm42": true,
  "48yULftKSxgyS84ZJC4hs4ug4Ei2": true
}
```

Read that linked blog post for more info, but in short, it makes adding/removing users really simple:

```
const groupRef = firebase.database.ref(`Groups/${groupId}`);

// add a user
groupRef.child("E04HLbIjGDRUQxsRReHSKifaXIr2").set(true);

// remove a user
groupRef.child("KEuhrxnAWXS0dnotjhjFAYUOcm42").remove();
```

You can also change `true` to whatever you want. Here are some examples:

- `false` = participant, `true` = moderator
- `false` = read-only, `true` = can edit
- Role names: `"member"`, `"admin"`, `"moderator"`, etc.
- Privilege levels: `0` (member), `500` (moderator), `1000` (owner), etc. (make sure to space these out, you don't want to have to add in a level between `0` and `1` and have to edit your entire database).

The most important point though, is that Realtime Database security rules don't know about arrays. `data.val()` won't return an array, it will just return a sentinel value that says "non-null object is here!". This means a map is necessary for security rules.

[This reference document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database) covers the structure and variables you can use in your Realtime Database Security Rules.

With your proposed rules, you attempt to allow any user in the group to be able to write to the group's data - but you don't manage what they can and can't write to. Any malicious member of a group could add/delete anyone else, make themselves the owner, or even delete the group entirely.

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "Groups" : {
      "$group": {
        // If this group doesn't exist, allow the read.
        // If the group does exist, only the owner & it's members
        // can read this group's entire data tree.
        ".read": "!data.exists() || (auth != null && (data.child('Owner').val() === auth.uid || data.child('Allowed').child(auth.uid).val() === true))",

        "Owner": {
          // Only the current owner can write data to this key if it exists.
          // If the owner is not yet set, they can only claim it for themselves.
          ".write": "auth != null && (data.val() === auth.uid || (!data.exists() && newData.val() === auth.uid))",

          // Force this value to be a string
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        },

        "Allowed": {
          // Only the owner can edit the entire member list
          // For a new group, the owner is also granted write access
          // for it's creation
          ".write": "auth != null && (data.parent().child('Owner').val() === auth.uid || (!data.exists() && newData.parent().child('Owner').val() === auth.uid))",

          "$member": {
            // Allows the user to remove themselves from the group
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid === $member && !newData.exists()",

            // Force this value to be a boolean
            ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()"
          }
        },

        "Data": {
          // The owner and members can edit anything under "Data"
          // Currently this includes deleting everything under it!
          // For a new group, the owner is also granted write access
          // for it's creation
          // TODO: tighten structure of "Data" like above
          ".write": "auth != null && (data.parent().child('Owner').val() === auth.uid || data.parent().child('Allowed').child(auth.uid).val() === true || (!data.exists() && newData.parent().child('Owner').val() === auth.uid))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So I'm pretty new to this thanks for the Insight! when you speak of a map could I use a Dictionary (c#) or is that basically the same thing? Because as you said currently I am using a list. Tomorrow I'll try to implement that. Giving you the solved. Ill comment if I have any questions.

Comment: Correct. For this type of mapping `C#` you would be using a `IDictionary{string, bool}`

Comment: So implemented it like this and it worked like a charm! Thanks for all the information!

Comment: How can you query for all groups the user has access to? Do you need to do individual queries for all groups?

Comment: @SimonTran Your best option would be to build a "userId->groupId=true" index. Each user would have their groups stored under `/GroupMembership/{userId}` in the same way as you store user IDs under `Allowed` (i.e `/GroupMembership/{userId}/{someGroupId} = true`). To get that users groups, you'd just pull down `/GroupMembership/{userId}`. While you could query the data under `/Groups` directly, it would require downloading all the data just to sift through it - which is slow, inefficient and causes problems for handling permissions.

Comment: querying `/GroupMembership/{userId}` returns a list of group ids, correct? Once I get that list, I still need to individually query `/Groups/{groupId}` for each id. Isn't this bad for performance?

Comment: @SimonTran heyo, you ever figure this out? im wondering the same thing. on top of this, how can you sort by the last time the group was updated or there was a message sent? i was thinking of of instead of storing true as the value to `/GroupMembership/{userId}/{someGroupId}`, i would store the timestamp of the last time it was updated/there was a message sent. but then i would have to update this value for every single users GroupMembership field when ever there is an update to the group, or a message sent. seems unreasonable :(